# Design or Plugin suggestion for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a WP site which will have multiple subjects. Each subject will have multiple lessons and each lesson will have meta data like title, description etc etc. A User will be allowed to read some lessons and based on number of lessons read, he will be assigned some custom badges.

While showing any lesson, we should be able to show the list of users who have already read that lesson.

To get this done on WP, I am planning to use some Custom Content Type Plugin which I can use to create Subject, Lessons and the User Meta to store users action on any lesson. The Badges can also be made part of Users Meta.

The Problem I see are

1. I dont know any way to map Subjects to Lessons i.e while creating a new lesson, I should be able to map it to one subject (like we do node linking in Drupal )
2. I am not use if User meta table can be used to store many to many info like "XYZ user have read 25 lessons" and "ABC Lesson was read by 10 Users"

What should be the best design for this kind of Application.

Comment: cant you dolve problem 1 with categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know any way to map Subjects to Lessons i.e while creating a new lesson, I should be able to map it to one subject (like we do node linking in Drupal )

Why don't you set up the subjects as categories? Then when you create each lesson you can map it to the subject category.

Answer (score 1):

cant you solve problem 1 with categories?

And if you save each 'read' in the usermeta with each lesson having an unique meta. You could just count those.